# How to install java 1.1 on 64-bit Windows with no folder called AppData?

Tags: java, versioning, appdata

Recently i have been working with a project that requires Java 1.1 version. But whenever i try to run the 
jdk-1_1_8_006-win.exe file , I have been receiving a message as shown below.

Image showing error:

[image: Image showing error]

After clicking ok on that:

[image: After clicking ok on that]

I have seen one answer in stack overflow like

> Get the Java installer files.
>
> Execute jdk-1_1_8_010-windows-i586.exe When the error dialog is
>   displayed, open C:\USERS(User Name)\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\~EXB0000 (Do
>   not click the OK button at this time) Copy all files to another folder
>   Click the ok button Download the tool and execute it.
>
> Download Is3Engine.zip (ReactOS's InstallSheild Engine 3.0) Extract
>   Is3Engine.zip (containssetup.exe) Move setup32.exe to the copied Java
>   installers Execute setup32.exe

But the issue here is I am unable to find an Folder called APPDATA in my PC.

Comment: Java 1.1? As in "The Java version released 23 years ago"? Unless that project is purely for software archaeological reasons, run away from it quickly. This can **not** be a healthy work environment, if that is still a requirement. And if circumstances force you into continuing this work, chances are you're *way* better off working in a VM with a 32 bit version of Windows installed. And last but not least: given how rare Java 1.1 (rightfully) is these days, there's a good chance that your colleagues on that project know more than average internet people about  it.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Actually the main issue is i have a simulation environment (in java) where there are some .class files generating some random numbers.. when i try to run it on my 64 bit pc with jdk 1.8.0 it is giving results unsimilar to the mentioned results by the author of simulator.. the simulator was designed in 2009 . So i was just trying to run simulator on all jde versions so that i can stop at a version where i can get accurate results as mentioned by author

Comment: Then the Virtual Machine Approach seems even more feasible, I'm pretty sure that's easier then getting that ancient piece of software to run on a modern OS. Maybe skip 1.1 and check if 1.2 or 1.3 run it as expected.

Comment: In 2009 Java 6 was current and IIRC everything below 5 obsolete. And for at least the last free update of 6 (6u45 in 2013) both 32bit and 64bit install okay on Win64. because my oldest Windows test machine (still) has them.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, this isn't due to AppData not being there; if it wasn't, your system would break in all kinds of weird ways. It's hidden and system, because messing with it can break it, but it's still there; you can change Explorer's settings if you really want to see it.

This error is because 16-bit software can't run on 64-bit Windows, and out of sheer inertia, the use of 16-bit installers continued all the way into the early 2000s. Windows x64 has workarounds for a few common ones, like Installshield and NSIS, but anything other than that will instantly fail.

There's really nothing you can or ideally should do other than installing it on a VM of an older system that it was meant to run on.

Comment: Although wikipedia says Java 1.1 was in 1997, which was before even 2k or ME -- and before _any_ amd64/x86-64

Answer (score 0):

`APPDATA` is hidden directory.
In Windows Explorer, enable the ”Hidden items" checkbox under "Show/Hide" under the ”View” menu item.

Alternatively, you can display it using the following method.

1. Press `Win + R` (opens the Run dialog).
2. Type `%appdata%`
3. Press OK button.

[Windows AppData folder: Show and manage application data - IONOS](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/show-windows-appdata-folder/)